# What happens when we combine parts of two half wave plates?

Tags: optics, polarization

A half wave plate mirrors the polarization of light in its optic axis. Now suppose we 'combine' two half wave plates (or rather, their birefringent material) as shown in the figure below. I could write this all out in equations, but I think my figure makes it easier to get the idea across.


We are looking in the direction of propagation of light. We have the material of the first half wave plate in pink, with its optic axis shown in dark gray. Suppose this material were to span the entire surface, linearly polarized light as shown in red would simply be mirrored (in this case counter clockwise) in this axis. Similarly, we have another half wave plate in light blue, with its optic axis in light gray. Again, were this material to span the entire surface, polarized light as shown in dark blue would be mirrored in this axis, but now counter clockwise.

My question is, what would happen to the polarization of light if we were to construct a 'plate' precisely as shown in the figure? Thus, we cut away at the two wave plates and place them in the four quadrants as shown. How could I describe this using a Jones matrix?

[image]

As I understand it, a half wave plate 'splits' the incoming polarization into two components, along its optic axis and perpendicular to it, which will have different speeds because of the different refractive indexes. However, now the perpendicular axis lies inside another material, which in turn has different refractive indexes, and to make things worse, the perpendicular axis of this material lies inside the other material, and again, and again etc...
How can this be solved? In addition, could there be a material which would rotate the polarization clockwise or counter clockwise depending on the direction of polarization of the incoming light?

Comment: HInt:  apply the first Jones matrix,  take the output vector & apply the next Jones matrix to it, and so on.